# I want to know another method of integration to compute $\int \frac1{a+b\sin x}\ \mathsf dx$

Tags: integration, complex-integration

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{1}{a+b\sin(x)} dx 
= \frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}} ~ \text{if} ~ a^2 > b^2
$$

I know the trick substituting $y=\tan(x/2)$
But I'd like to know another method.

For example using COMPLEX INTEGRAL...
(but I did not find yet.)

Could you give me some source?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: For someone who has been on this site as long as you have, I would suggest that you learn the proper way of formatting. There is a very helpfull tutorial that can be found [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Moreover, by using the search feature you will find many different approaches for solving your integral.

Comment: Thank you for yous comment. I'll keep in mind. I apologize for having caused trouble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

Use: $z=e^{ix}$, $dx=\frac{1}{i z} dz$.

You get an rational function and the contour of integration is now the unit circle. Utilizing Residue Theorem you will get the stated result.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you for answering. I followed your advice // sinx = {e^(ix) - e^(-ix)}/2i → Let e^(ix) = z, then dz = iz dx → Therefore 'the integral' = int 2/z(2ai+bz-b/z) dz = int 2/(bz^2 + 2azi - b) dz ★ I'll do it more and more.. THANKYOU

Comment: THANK YOU // I have done :-)